# pandas data frame merge on one of duplicate indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame with timestamps as indexes, it may occur that the timestamp (so the index as well) is a duplicate sometimes, i wish to keep this data since this contains information.

```
               Job state
10:05:50  printing     a
10:07:50    finish     a
10:07:50       NaN  idle
10:10:08  printing     b
10:13:08    finish     b
10:13:08       NaN  idle
10:15:44  printing     c
10:18:44    finish     c
10:18:44       NaN  idle
10:20:21  printing     d
10:23:21    finish     d
10:23:21       NaN  idle
```

I then have a second data frame which i wish to combine on one of the indexes, but not both since this will mess with my calculation further on.

```
                     duration
2023-03-22 10:07:50  00:02:18
2023-03-22 10:13:08  00:02:36
2023-03-22 10:18:44  00:01:37
```

doing the normal concat will combine on indexes but i get it double, i want it only on one of the duplicate indexes.

```
IN:
resultRich = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)
```

```
OUT:
                          Job state  duration
2023-03-22 10:05:50  printing     a       NaN
2023-03-22 10:07:50    finish     a  00:02:18
2023-03-22 10:07:50       NaN  idle  00:02:18
2023-03-22 10:10:08  printing     b       NaN
2023-03-22 10:13:08    finish     b  00:02:36
2023-03-22 10:13:08       NaN  idle  00:02:36
2023-03-22 10:15:44  printing     c       NaN
2023-03-22 10:18:44    finish     c  00:01:37
2023-03-22 10:18:44       NaN  idle  00:01:37
2023-03-22 10:20:21  printing     d       NaN
2023-03-22 10:23:21    finish     d       NaN
2023-03-22 10:23:21       NaN  idle       NaN
```

So what i want is

````
                          Job state  duration
2023-03-22 10:05:50  printing     a       NaN
2023-03-22 10:07:50    finish     a       Nan
2023-03-22 10:07:50       NaN  idle  00:02:18
2023-03-22 10:10:08  printing     b       NaN
2023-03-22 10:13:08    finish     b       Nan
2023-03-22 10:13:08       NaN  idle  00:02:36
2023-03-22 10:15:44  printing     c       NaN
2023-03-22 10:18:44    finish     c       Nan
2023-03-22 10:18:44       NaN  idle  00:01:37
2023-03-22 10:20:21  printing     d       NaN
2023-03-22 10:23:21    finish     d       NaN
2023-03-22 10:23:21       NaN  idle       NaN```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` the inputs, simply assign to the last duplicate:

```
df1.loc[~df1.index.duplicated(keep='last'), 'duration'] = df2['duration']
```

If you want to fix the already existing column (e.g. after `concat`):

```
resultRich.loc[resultRich.index.duplicated(keep='last'), 'duration'] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
                          Job state  duration
2023-03-22 10:05:50  printing     a       NaN
2023-03-22 10:07:50    finish     a       NaN
2023-03-22 10:07:50       NaN  idle  00:02:18
2023-03-22 10:10:08  printing     b       NaN
2023-03-22 10:13:08    finish     b       NaN
2023-03-22 10:13:08       NaN  idle  00:02:36
2023-03-22 10:15:44  printing     c       NaN
2023-03-22 10:18:44    finish     c       NaN
2023-03-22 10:18:44       NaN  idle  00:01:37
2023-03-22 10:20:21  printing     d       NaN
2023-03-22 10:23:21    finish     d       NaN
2023-03-22 10:23:21       NaN  idle       NaN
```

Alternative with `assign`:

```
resultRich = df1.assign(duration=df2['duration'].reindex(df1.index).mask(lambda s: s.index.duplicated(keep='last')))
```